# Listbox SelectionMode does not work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which contains some items. I want to implement :

1) CTRL key to select different items.

2) Tab key to change items.

3) Shift + tab control..

- I am using `SelectionMode=Extended`, but CTRL does not work, why?
- When I am pressing tab it switch only on first item, why?

**Xaml:**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="{Binding PathCoords}" Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="path" Value="#FFCF2222"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="path" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>   
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle2}" Focusable="True"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Code:**

```
namespace WpfApplication13
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new Data();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Element
{
    public string PathCoords { get; set; }
    public string Margin { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public List<Element> Items { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        Items = new List<Element>();
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M52,92L89.5,57.5 99.5,100.5z" });
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M131,104L150.5,39.5 204.5,87.5 155.5,88.5z" ,Margin="131,39.5,0,0"});
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M232,105L231.5,49.5 294.5,49.5 291.5,97.5z", Margin = "231.5,49.5,0,0" });
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M75,183L85.5,154.5 107.5,185.5z", Margin = "75,154.5,0,0" });
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M167,222L166.5,169.5 230.5,190.5z", Margin = "166.5,169.5,0,0" });
        Items.Add(new Element { PathCoords = "M258,199L273.5,146.5 332.5,161.5 327.5,207.5z", Margin = "258,146.5,0,0" });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SelectionMode=Extended` to work, there has to be a `Trigger` in your `ListBox` to notify the `CheckBox` that a new `ListBoxItem` has been selected.

Currently you can select multiple items however the `CheckBox` inside only one of them will get focus thus only the color of one `Path` will change.

Therefore if you set the condition in the triggers for your `CheckBox` to `IsChecked` instead of `IsFocused` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
     ...
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="path" Value="#FFCF2222"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="path" Value="2"/>
        </Trigger>
     ...
</Style>
```

And then add a proper `DataTrigger` for your `ListBox.ItemTemplate` as below:

```
</ListBox>
    ...
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="chb" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle2}" Focusable="True"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=
                                    {x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="chb" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then multi-selection should work.